# Consider any of the faces, e.g. the blue one, should I call it one panel or 9 panels?

Tags: word-choice

There are 3 colored faces - white, red and blue in the following Rubik's Cube image.

[image]

the sentence from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube

> Some later versions of the cube have been updated to use colored plastic panels instead, which prevents peeling and fading.

uses the term "panel" without defining it explicitly.

Consider any of the faces, e.g. the blue one, should I call it one panel or 9 panels?

Comment: Each face is a *side* or a *face*, but calling a face a "panel" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer "square" over "panel," which is what is used throughout the rest of the Wikipedia article. That sentence uses "panel" because the colored plastic panels are the physical objects that the stickers were replaced with--it is not implying that the smaller squares are called panels.

If you're referring to a single face, both "face" and "side" are acceptable (and used throughout the article).

Answer (score 0):

It's arbitrary, but *you* should explicitly define "panel" in *your* document. You could preface it that, *in this document*, "panel" refers to a complete face of the Rubik's Cube, and "face" refers to the portion of the component cubes on that panel.

Technical documents often require definitions be made explicit, as the words are used with a *precise* meaning, not just one colloquially used. If others have written on the topic, though, **use the standard technical vocabulary**. It would be humorous if a doctor referred to the "arm bone" without using the established name.

Comment: I have seen the coloured faces of the individual sub-cubes called 'stickers', I guess because some models were made that way, and I have heard of people getting so frustrated that they peel them all off and re-apply them to make a 'solved' Rubik's Cube.

Answer (score 0):

According to your quoted sentence, each face is composed of nine panels.  Panel, however, is a terrible term to refer to the nine units that make up a face, without somehow letting your reader know that's what is intended.

Specifically relating the existing stickers to panels helps to clarify things.  Once people know you are talking about the nine units that make up a face, they will know what *panel* means.

> Some later versions of the cube have been updated to use colored panels **instead of stickers**, which prevents peeling and fading.

Without having to explicitly define *panel*, I have let the reader know that it corresponds to the existing stickers.  Your original quoted sentence does not mention the stickers which makes it difficult to understand the usage of *panel*.